# Open PDF new browser tab ASP.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, response

I am trying to open a PDF in a new tab in the browser. So far I have been able to get the PDF in the browser within the "same" page. However I would now like it to open it in a new tab. However I am stuck on how to achieve this?

```
            Response.Clear()
            Response.ClearContent()
            Response.ClearHeaders()
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileId & fileExtension)
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytesReturned.Length.ToString())
            Response.OutputStream.Write(bytesReturned, 0, bytesReturned.Length)
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()
```

**Result:**
[image]

The result is displayed in a gridview, I would like to link each "view" button to a target"_blank" attribute. The **"ID"** corresponds to the file name.

From my research, I can see you can add a button in the aspx page and give it target "_blank" attribute but I am not sure how to link it to my displayPDF() method?

If the question is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: You have written this code just to open the file ?

Comment: Put that code in another asp page, and call it from JS with the _blank attribute.

Comment: <a href="/displaypdf.asp" target="_blank">VIew Pdf</a>?

Comment: The bytes are being returned from a database, the file name is displayed in a gridview. A view button is clicked to display the pdf current process...

Comment: @JimmyChandra how do I set this for every file displayed in a gridview?

Comment: @MairajAhmad please see revised question

Comment: @CapitánCavernícola can you expand on this pleasse?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make view button an anchor and set its attribute to _blank and second is to open file by using code behind.

Call this code on button click

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "a", "window.open('"+strFileId & fileExtension+"','_blank');", true);
```

Comment: The button is part of the gridview, I am calling the displayPDF method within the GridView_RowCommand handler. So where can I add this?

Comment: Add this where you have already added the code mentioned in your question i mean in the same place in GridView_rowCommand.

Comment: I have added it to after Response.End, but even now it will still open in the same page

Comment: I have commented out all the response code, but still not working?

Comment: What is value of  strFileId & fileExtension ?

Comment: Eg. StrFileId = "360_550-02" and fileExtension = ".pdf"

Comment: yes it is, is there a way to open it using a html anchor tag?